# How to bind class to the last item of array in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array to display like the following:

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in animals" :id="index" class="zoo" :class="`animal-${index}`"></div>
```

I want to add the class `last-animal` to the last item of animals, but I don't know how it can be done in template literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do this programmatically, you should be able to use the CSS [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) selector

```css
.zoo:last-child:after { /* this is your "last-animal" */
  content: ', oh my!';
}
.animal-0:before {
  content: '';
}
.animal-1:before {
  content: '';
}
.animal-2:before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<main>
<div id="0" class="zoo animal-0"></div>
<div id="1" class="zoo animal-1"></div>
<div id="2" class="zoo animal-2"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use condition here

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in animals" 
     :id="index" class="zoo" 
    :class="{index === animals.length - 1 ? 'last-animal' : `animal-${index}`}">
</div>
```

Comment: OP says they want to _add_ the `last-animal` class (not replace the `animal-${index}` one) so I think you'd want to use the [array syntax](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax)